# Nginx: Serve Files from different Root Locations

Tags: codeigniter, magento, nginx, php

Hej,

I have the following Situation: I have two Systems running (Magento and Codeigniter) that should operate under the same url. Magento is only responsible for a few urls:

`http://dev/checkout`, `http://dev/kasse` for example should be served by magento which lies in `/vagrant/magento`

All other request should be served by codeigniter which lies in `/vagrant/codeigniter`

I somewhat got it working, but it uses if's and I have to add the folder in two files, which is not nice. And php sometimes thinks its root lies in a wrong folder (`/vagrant/`, without the magento folder)

What am I doing wrong and how to do it right?

Thanks!

```
# ./sites-available/default

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        server_name rh.dev;

        root /vagrant/codeigniter/;

        location ~ /(kasse|tools|checkout|warenkorb|skin|media) {
                alias /vagrant/magento/;
                index index.php;

                try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        }

        location / {
                index index.php;

                if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$") {
                        access_log off;
                        expires max;
                }

                try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        }

        location @handler {
                rewrite / /index.php;
        }

        location ~.php/ {
                rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
        }

        include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
}

# ./php.conf

fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    set $php_root /vagrant/codeigniter/;

    if ( $request_uri ~ /(kasse|tools|checkout|warenkorb|skin|media) ) {
        set $php_root /vagrant/magento/;
    }

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

# ./fastcgi_params

fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I advice you to take a backup of your conf file before starting all this.

Anyway, you were doing great at first, but then you added stuff that didn't need to be added, like for example

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
```

This line doesn't really need to be split into two, you could just merge the rewrite into it

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

But then it makes me wonder how it's working without the `$request_uri`, so if doesn't work i would try using this line instead:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
```

---

Now this block i don't really understand what it's supposed to do

```
location ~.php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

I'd say it's safe to remove it entirely, cause it seems to be rewriting the request to the same thing it was.

---

And inside the php conf, the whole if thing is not necessary, it's understood from the path and location blocks of the file

```
set $php_root /vagrant/codeigniter/;

if ( $request_uri ~ /(kasse|tools|checkout|warenkorb|skin|media) ) {
    set $php_root /vagrant/magento/;
}
```

I'd say try to remove all this and it's supposed to be still working

Comment: Hum, it wasn't working in the first place, thats why I'm asking. The problem with not settings the root by myself in the `php.conf` php thinks the root lies in `/vagrant/codeigniter/`. Thts why I added the if in there to control that, but it felt not right. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: try replace `alias` with `root`, read http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias and you'll find exactly your problem description